# Show a large-size image when click on thumbnail and giving opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I think It's better that I explain like this:

1. There are 6 small images on the page next to each other
2. user clicks on one of them
3. all of the 5 other images (except for the image that the user clicked) will have an opacity of 0.7
4. A large version of the image (the image that the user has been selected) will show. ( I have an img tag and the image src will replace the src of the tag )

Can you tell me how can I do that? I prefer using JavaScript and Angular JS, But if you need it, there's no problem if you use JQuery too. sorry for bad English. Thank you
**Update:** some user asked me what I tried... This is my code and I know It will not work... that's why I'm asking this from you...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa-IR" data-ng-app="projects" data-ng-controller="projects_controller">
<!-- Website design by Mohsen_Nirouzad -->
<head>
   <!-- Adding meta information -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="Mohsen Nirouzad - http://AproZ.ir">
    <!-- defining stylesheets DO NOT delete the bellow codes if you don't have enough knowledge of web design -->
    <!-- I used w3data.min.js for javascript templating engine so you've to change the bellow information in script tag -->
    <meta name="application-name" content="{{application_name}}">
    <meta name="description" content="{{description}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}">
    <meta name="publisher" content="{{googleplus_url}}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{page_title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/w3rtl.min.css">
    <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
   <body>
    <div data-ng-include="'variables/sidenav.html'"></div>
    <div style="margin-right:25%" class="w3-row-padding">
       <div class="w3-col s6">
           <div data-ng-include="'variables/logo1.html'"></div>
           <div class="w3-row-padding">
               <div class="w3-col">
                   <div class="w3-col s6">
                       <img src="{{img1}}" alt="{{img1_alt}}" title="{{img1_title}}"><br>
                       <img src="{{img2}}" alt="{{img2_alt}}" title="{{img2_title}}"><br>
                       <img src="{{img3}}" alt="{{img3_alt}}" title="{{img3_title}}">
                   </div>
                   <div class="w3-col s6">
                       <img src="{{img4}}" alt="{{img4_alt}}" title="{{img4_title}}"><br>
                       <img src="{{img5}}" alt="{{img5_alt}}" title="{{img5_title}}"><br>
                       <img src="{{img6}}" alt="{{img6_alt}}" title="{{img6_title}}">
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR">
                  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR">
                  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR">
                  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR">
                  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR">
                  <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR">
                  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR">
                  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
              </a>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="w3-col s6">
           
       </div>
       </div>
    <div data-ng-include="'variables/footer.html'"></div>
    <script>
        var application = angular.module('projects',[]);
        application.controller('projects_controller',function($scope){
        $scope.description='Some Description',
        $scope.keywords='key1,key2,key3',
        $scope.application_name='Sarabon',
        $scope.googleplus_url='#',
        $scope.page_title='پروژه ها'
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added my code but it's incomplete so It will not work...

Comment: Why minus points? I just wanted to get an answer... :(

Comment: Yes, I agree. Why minus pint. You SHOULD advice before you do minus vote. Really disappointing when someone doesn't mention anything just do a minus vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-click` to set a scope variable like `selectedImage` which can be used in `ng-class` and `ng-src` for big image

```
// small image
<img ng-src="{{img1}}" 
     alt="{{img1_alt}}" 
     title="{{img1_title}}" 
     ng-click="selectImage(img1)"
     ng-class="{'low-opacity-class' : selectedImage && selectedImage != img1}}"

>
// big image
<img ng-if="selectedImage" ng-src="selectedImage ">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.selectedImage = null;
$scope.selectImage=function(img){
   $scope.selectedImage = img;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I understood what I have to do :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a big hidden div that takes the whole screen and create an img tag in it without src attribute. in "onClick" event (onClick is for js. I don't know how angular handles clicks!), set that div visible (using css "display property") and set image's src to what you want. 
css for the fullscreen div can be like this:

```css
.fullscreen{
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0
  }
```

```html
<div class = "fullscreen">
  <img src="#"/>
</div>
```

then you just need to add a few code lines to change display property of the div and change src attribute of img to your desired one.

Comment: `onclick` doesn't belong in angular apps

Comment: thank you for your helpful comment, And can you tell me how can I define for page that when user click on one image, It give a opacity to other images?